VSCode editBuilder implicitly accepts suggestions
UPD:
Never mind I am just bad at reading sources!
I am using Colonize extension.
The extension adding ; at the end of the line by hitting Shift + Enter.
However when I get suggestions they get selected. I don't want this.
First thing I thought of is to check the repo issues : one person also thinks the same.
Then I decided to check source code and I don't see anything that actually selects the suggestion.
I've tried to add to  keybindings.json  all commands to be disabled, and it works without colonize!
    {
        "key": "shift+Enter",
        "command": "-acceptSelectedSuggestion",
        "when": "true"
    },
    {
        "key": "shift+Enter",
        "command": "-acceptSelectedSuggestionOnEnter",
        "when": "true"
    },

    {
      "key": "shift+enter",
      "command": "-acceptAlternativeSelectedSuggestion",
      "when": "true"
    }

The logical next step would be to check the source code of the extension.  Fortunately it is very short and it just uses editBuilder to insert semicolon.
I suspect that this statement could be the issue, but after commenting this portion in js file of the extension nothing changed it terms of accepting the suggestion :
  vscode.commands.executeCommand("acceptSelectedSuggestion").then(() => {
    var lineIndex = editor.selection.active.line;
    var lineObject = editor.document.lineAt(lineIndex);
    var lineLength = lineObject.text.length;

    if (
      lineObject.text.charAt(lineLength - 1) !== ";" &&
      !lineObject.isEmptyOrWhitespace
    ) {
      var insertionSuccess = editor.edit((editBuilder) => {
        editBuilder.insert(new vscode.Position(lineIndex, lineLength), ";lol"); // MOD HERE!
      });

      if (!insertionSuccess) return;
    }

    if (option === "hold") return;

    // MOD HERE !
    // option === 'endline'
    //   ? vscode.commands.executeCommand('cursorEnd')
    //   : vscode.commands.executeCommand('editor.action.insertLineAfter')
  });

Here is a demo gif (lol shows that I made modification):

Steps to Reproduce:

Download the extension
Start typing to see suggestioins
Press shift + Enter
Watch semicolon added and first suggestion get accepted

  Version: 1.95.3 (user setup)
  Commit: f1a4fb101478ce6ec82fe9627c43efbf9e98c813
  Date: 2024-11-13T14:50:04.152Z
  Electron: 32.2.1
  ElectronBuildId: 10427718
  Chromium: 128.0.6613.186
  Node.js: 20.18.0
  V8: 12.8.374.38-electron.0
  OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22631


First make sure you don't have any extensions that affect the suggestions.
Try overriding the behavior of these keys directly, write in keybindings.json
{
    "key": "shift+enter",
    "command": "colonize.insertSemicolonAtEndOfLine",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
}

You can try disabling autocompletion by writing in settings.json
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "off"

If it's not too imperative that shift+enter is used, you can just change the binding :)
